# Selenium/Firefox Twitter login succeeds but Selenium/webdriver reports errors (python)

Tags: python, authentication, selenium-webdriver, firefox, twitter

As i said in title the code below thinks it failed and quits dumping errors BUT the page proceeds to next phase asking for password, etc. I can confirm that the username text is correctly entered.
Error in python occurs *whether I send "enter" key or click() at end of text input*. I'm using Xpath to select elements (PS i'm no front end guy, so maybe i'm doing something wrong)

```
SEL_DRIVER = webdriver.Firefox(service=Service(GeckoDriverManager().install()))

class TwitterBot():
    def __init__(self,username,password):
        self.browser=SEL_DRIVER
        self.username=username
        self.password=password
        
    def signIn(self):
        self.browser.get("https://www.twitter.com/login")
        # time.sleep(2)
        # usernameInput=self.browser.find_element_by_name("session[username_or_email]")
        # usernameInput=self.browser.find_element(by = By.XPATH,
                                                # value= '''/html/body/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[5]/label/div/div[2]/div/input''')
        
        wait = WebDriverWait(self.browser, 30)
        usernameInput = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, "text")))
        usernameInput.send_keys(self.username)
        
        input("Press Enter to continue...")
        
        # usernameInput.send_keys(Keys.ENTER) ### doesnt work , throws error
        
        usernameBtn=self.browser.find_element(by = By.XPATH,
                                              value= '''/html/body/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[6]/div''')        

        input("Press Enter...")
        usernameBtn.click() 
        .........
```

ERROR in Jupyter book-

```
Cell In[3], line 32, in TwitterBot.signIn(self)
     29 usernameBtn.click()
...
RemoteError@chrome://remote/content/shared/RemoteError.sys.mjs:8:8
WebDriverError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.sys.mjs:180:5
NoSuchElementError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.sys.mjs:392:5
element.find/</<@chrome://remote/content/marionette/element.sys.mjs:133:16
```

Comment: it seems to have caught the exception thrown by this line:  usernameBtn=self.browser.find_element(by = By.XPATH,
                                              value= '''/html/body/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[6]/div''')        This happens right after pressing enter (user presses enter?)  and has no webdriverwait which would ignore no such element for a specified time.  I would use a webdriverwait with expected condition of tobeclickable.  The xpath should be improved too...  use an ID if it has one.

Comment: Thx. A clarification, no User interaction ever. Error occurs whether a **click()** is issued or **send_keys(Keys.ENTER)** is sent. I will try playing with **webdriverwait**

Comment: This is looking like a Firefox Web driver issue. Same xpath args work fine on Chrome. I'm forced to switch to Chrome in interest of time.